# Are there any restrictions as to the content of a dijit.StackContainer?

Tags: dojo

Are there any restrictions regarding the elements that can be posted inside of the ContentPane of a dijit StackContainer? I'm asking this because I'm trying to put some div's inside it but when doing so, the content from the second Pane is displayed in the first one and the second Pane's button does not apear at all. (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only widgets are supported within StackContainer.  Same for all descendants of dijit._Container.

If you want to add simple HTML, it should be wrapped in a ContentPane.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know that. That was what I was asking. About HTML "inside of the ContentPane of a dijit StackContainer". Could it be that the bad formatting is due to the fact that I have PHP embeded in the HTML?

Comment: Solved. The ContenPane accepts any HTML element, JavaScript and PHP script in it. The problems I encounter were due to an error in the JavaScript  embedded in the ContentPane.

Comment: If this does, in fact, answer your question, please edit this answer to describe exactly what you did and then set it as your chosen answer.